# Etymology and meaning of the word "pizzled"

Tags: meaning, etymology

I heard of a term today called "pizzled" and am confused about it as there is a plethora of different definitions for the word.

I first heard it in a speech by David Shing TNW Europe Conference. He said that it was a combination of "pissed" and "puzzled." I immediately thought it was made up and that it is new slang.

But then after further investigation I found traces to a short story where it was used in a strange way in 1955, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autofac.

In addition, Wikipedia said "pizzle" is an old english word for penis, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizzle. In addition Wiktionary had the following: "Having the penis in a different tincture than the rest of the body."

What is the etymology and meaning of this strange word?

Comment: In “Autofac”, the word is apparently intended to be meaningless, so that the autofac cannot process it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't new but you are right, it is confusing.  Interestingly, it is used in medical slang (Dictionary of medical slang -Jacob Edward) and it is defined as exhausted, or to its point:

> Pizzle chewer ... A female who relieves a male of his phallic tension
>   by fondling the instrument in her mouth.
>
> Pizzle-grinder ... 1. A butcher. 2. A prostitute.
>
> Pizzle honker ... A prostitute who satisfies her patrons by manual
>   friction.
>
> Pizzle warmer . . . The pudendum muliebre, esp. the vagina.
>
> **Pizzled** . . . Exhausted physically or mentally.

[Etymology: pizzle (n.) "penis of a bull used as a flogging instrument," 1520s, from Low German pesel or Flemish pezel, diminutive of root of Dutch pees "sinew," from Old Low German root *pisa.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pizzle&searchmode=none)

Comment: +1 One, presumably, has to be very careful when locating the services of a pizzle-grinder. The subtle difference between Arrgh and Aaaah.

Comment: The question is what costs more, the woman (or man), or a steak

Comment: Steak! I'd be lucky to get a small chipolata these days.

Comment: I'll start a 'Crowdsource Funding' for a steak dinner. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

My interpretation of Pizzled is to be exposed to the elements: Example...
He went camping in the high country..the weather changed and he was Pizzled by the wind and rain..
When he returned home a friend asked:How was your camping holiday?
He said..I copped a Pizzling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).